# Bean method in onclick is fired on rendering

Tags: html, jsf, onclick

The following works as expected, only when a click-event occurs:

```
<a onclick="alert('test')"/>
```

but this is already called while page-rendering:

```
<a onclick="#{bean.someMethod()}" />
```

Why is the bean method called while rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onclick` expects a javascript function, not a method expression. `#{bean.someMethod()}` has to be resolved to some string (`alert('test')` in your example) when the page is rendered, that's why it is called. `<a onClick="#{bean.someMethod()}" />` only makes sense if `someMethod()` returns a string which is valid javascript code.

This is not to be confused for JSF `action` attribute for example, like `<h:commandButton action="#{bean.someMethod()}"`, which is called when the button is clicked.

Comment: in the context of the question it is maybe better to change the `h:commandButton` example to an `h:commandLink` one.

Comment: Could be, but I don't think it is that important since the example was ment to point to all action source components.

Comment: I know, it is not a big deal, was just a small suggestion